# Thieves guild lock box reset

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the reset timer of the practice lock boxes in the thieves guild?

There are 5 lock boxes in the thieves guild with all the different difficulties for opening them. There is also a note in the middle of the chests that says:

> "These chests are for practice use only. Please Refrain from using
>   them for storage. The locks on these chests have been specially
>   constructed to reset themselves after a short amount of time. If you
>   have any issues, please speak to Niruin."

I talked with Niruin and he didn't have anything to say about reseting the chests.

I opened all of them then did about 10 different jobs for Delvin and Vex going from Riften to Markarth, Solitude, etc. I know I have been gone at least 10 game days and they are still not reset.

Any idea what the reset timer is?

Comment: It's honestly probably not even worth the effort waiting.  You'd probably spend more time waiting for them to reset than you would coming across other chests in various dungeons and forts.  The small skill points you get for picking master locks probably doesn't offset the effort you'd have to put into tracking when they reset.

Comment: just waited 10 days outside of the cistern in Riften and had no luck, the 10 day waiting period seems to be a myth. I've also heard that the locks reset after 48 hours but that's also a lie. (360. latest updates, all DLC. 5/18/13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they never reset.  I opened mine very early on in the game and countless hours of gameplay later, they are still open.  They seem to be glitched.

Comment: Mine reset once ... but never again.

Comment: Mine have reset twice now! I have no freaking clue what the interval was though. Also, since the last reset they seem to be flagged as owned, and when I try to open them, Sapphire and Vipir run over and yell at me.

Comment: hmm very buggy behavior...

Comment: Mine have reset at least once.  Haven't gone back to them lately to check again though.

Comment: I have experienced them resetting, but don't have any specific info about when they reset

Answer (score 5):

I read that they reset after 10 days of not visiting the cistern.

I haven't tried it yet, but its worth a shot: it's also the same time frame that many ores reset.

Comment: Hi LockSmith, welcome to Arqade! Where did you read this?

Comment: That sounds somewhat plausible because 10 days is how long it takes for uncleared locations to reset (30 days for cleared), but I've never seen them actually reset, and I've spent a lot of time away from the Cistern and Riften.

Answer (score 0):

In my game, they seem to reset every few games, however each time the lock pick snaps, you exit the lock picking mini game, and the required position of the pick changes. Only way to avoid this is with an unbreakable pick.

Just pulled a daedric war axe out of the master chest, which is awesome since I went up the light armor side.

Comment: You can avoid the lockpick resetting by making sure you're in stealth mode *and* hidden.  If anybody is watching you (the eye is open and says detected) then you only get one shot at a time.  This applies anywhere - not just on these chests.

Comment: You can also wait until 3 am to pick the locks, as the room is empty at that time. It's especially helpful to do this if you are leveling lockpicking by breaking picks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure yo do not visit the cistern for 10 days as well. It seems the respawn timer itself gets reset everytime you visit the Cistern.

Comment: This answer basically repeats another one in here, and just like that other one, cites no sources.

Answer (score 0):

I have done multiple playthroughs and ive never seen them reset.  Ive had new characters pick the chests then come back 40 plus (Realtime)  hours later with no reset.  This includes finishing TG, DB, Companions, War faction, and Main line.  If they do reset it seems random.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to glitch out and I'm guessing most of you did, you have to leave the city then wait 30 days, if you wait an extended period of time next to the thieves guild chests or in the thieves guild it will glitch and not recet (does not glitch if you wait in the ragid flagon) you can also glitch other locks this way as well to be careful not to glitch the museam like I did, I hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

They reset after you complete the mission in which the dark brotherhood santuary gets attacked.

Comment: Sounds like a coincidence to me.

Comment: As @kotekzot said, there is no reason for a quest in the DB and a chest in the thieve guild to be related.