# Are the locked containers in the Cisten Training Room safe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I joined the Thieves' Guild, and completed the questline. I usually train my lockpicking at those containers in the training room and they have loot in it. You know in this image at the back behind my character and follower.

[image: chests]

I unlocked all the chests and took their loot. I wondered if these containers are safe or not. Are these containers safe or not?

Comment: save, try it, find out, reload if not

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [Aside from containers in bought houses or guilds/organizations, are there other 'safe' containers which will store items permanently (won't reset)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36256/aside-from-containers-in-bought-houses-or-guilds-organizations-are-there-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[They're not supposed to be safe.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/thieves-guild-lock-box-reset)

But they might glitch out and never reset.  Either way I wouldn't use them for storage.

Comment: Well, what are the only chests that are safe? I know the Tribute Chests has resetting loot, so that isn't safe. Are the chests in front of the beds in the Cistern safe?